# Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier

Tags: typescript, editor, inversifyjs, graphical-language

I am working with a GLSP [Node server and Diagram VScode extension](https://github.com/eclipse-glsp/glsp-examples/tree/master/project-templates/node-json-vscode) in Typescript.

When I try to launch the application, I am getting the following error:

```
(node:36950) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: ModuleModelState
at _validateActiveBindingCount (/Users/christine.samarchi/Desktop/FORCE/solution-builder-vscode-extension/graphical-editor/glsp-server-node/node_modules/inversify/src/planning/planner.ts:113:23)
```

I've tried adding ModelState in my GModelDiagramModule file as follows:

```
    protected override bindModelState(): BindingTarget<ModelState> | undefined {
    return { service: ModuleModelState };
}
```

I am getting this error as well:

```
Property 'bindModelState' in type 'WorkflowDiagramModule' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'GModelDiagramModule'.
```

Does anyone have any clue what is this issue?

Comment: Having the same issue. Everything works great during development (via `npm run serve`), but if I run `npm run build` and upload the compiled app to my webspace, this error is thrown: `Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol(MyService); _ planner.ts:113 [...]`